# How can I quickly copy a GPT partition scheme from one hard drive to another?

Tags: partition, sgdisk

On a non GPT partition table I can do

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sda | sfdisk /dev/sdb
```

But `sfdisk` doesn't support GPT partition tables. What can I use instead?

I'm looking for a one or two command solution, not just using GNU parted to output the partition sizes and then manually making them again.

Comment: Good reference to this Q on AU as well: http://askubuntu.com/questions/57908/how-can-i-quickly-copy-a-gpt-partition-scheme-from-one-hard-drive-to-another

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Install [gdisk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/) which is available from sourceforge as well as from the Ubuntu Universe repositories.

Then use the `sgdisk` command ([man page here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man8/sgdisk.8.html)) like so

```
sgdisk -R /dev/sdb /dev/sda
sgdisk -G /dev/sdb
```

The first command copies the partition table of `sda` to `sdb` (be careful not to mix these up). The second command randomizes the GUID on the disk and all the partitions. This is only necessary if the disks are to be used in the same machine, otherwise it's unnecessary.