# How to migrate partitions/file systems/swap to a new drive without any data using a shell script?

Tags: arch-linux, gpt, migration

Wishing to replace the system drive with near identical sized new and fresh SSD, or even a larger one, leaves me with a puzzle. `dd` is great and I can't use that bit-by-bit copy technique f.e. because my source drive died or is unreliable. I have a backup of all the data available.

The issue is how to backup and restore and/or migrate/clone the **GPT** partitioned drive structure **using a script** without its files and directories:

1. partitioning
2. file systems (and their properties)
3. swap

A search here for "migrate new drive -lvm" returns 30 results, none of them give me a hint.

Is there some kind of handy scriptable `parted --backup` and `--restore` command to accomplish this task in a minimal Arch Linux installation, that is UEFI booted?

Answer (score 1):

You can find many ways to copy the partition table here: [How to copy the partition layout of a whole disk using standard tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12986/how-to-copy-the-partition-layout-of-a-whole-disk-using-standard-tools)

After that you still need to format each partition with its specific filesystem type. You can surely automate that part from the partition list, however I doubt I would be worthwhile as there are some options you might need/want at filesystem creation that you can not derive from current ones (or you are just taking the opportunity of a new disk to format things with new options)

Answer (score 0):

To copy and restore a partition table you can use `fdisk`. Make sure you're using a modern version of `fdisk` though. That should be the case on an up to date [Arch Linux `fdisk`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fdisk).

```
fdisk /dev/disk/by-id/bus-model

O

partitions.txt
```

Then to load it back

```
fdisk /dev/disk/by-id/bus-model

I

partitions.txt
```

Comment: Arch 4.18.5: `fdisk: cannot open /dev/disk/by-id/bus-model: No such file or directory`