# Will sfdisk partition copy touch RAID data

Tags: mdadm, software-raid, sfdisk

A recent Ubuntu server reboot caused two of the SOFT RAID5 disk (/dev/sdd and /dev/sdf) losing its partition table (/dev/sdd1 and /dev/sdf1),  I have tried to use R-Studio that can directly connect to the drive image and R-Studio scan can see the file system. there is a good chance the RAID data is still there on the disk just I cannot access it.

Assuming the disk RAID data is store there, if I can figure out a way to get the partition table back by cloning the partition table from other RAID member disk in the RAID (/dev/sda, /dev/sdb, /dev/sdc, identical model size) using the [sfdisk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12986/how-to-copy-the-partition-layout-of-a-whole-disk-using-standard-tools?newreg=03a3a4b627b940caaef9e7eb203ba6cc) command to this disk, will it 1) destroy/touch the RAID data on /dev/sdd 2) make mdadm assemble still able to use the data on the "new" /dev/sdd1 partition?

Comment: What RAID, which RAID level? If it's something else than RAID 0, why don't you simply re-format it and add it to the RAID as a new disk? The RAID should build the disk back on its own.

Comment: I guess `/dev/hdd` is an hardware RAID (on the other hand, we would have `/dev/md0` or something like this, but it must be confirmed (and you quote `mdadm` which deals with software RAID). Note, that if it has no or a corrupted partition table, `sfdisk` won't be able to copy anything interesting.

Comment: It is a mdadm RAID 5, problem is I have two such disks  in the RAID suffering similar  partition issue, so it cannot recover automatically.